# Passing Optional parms in Python

Tags: python, path

I want to have the parameter for `childDir` to be optional.

```
def saveFile(parentDir, *childDir, fileName):
    # directory to store data
    DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).parent/parentDir/childDir/fileName
    # create dir_path if it does not exist
    Path(DIR_PATH).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    return DIR_PATH

saveFile("dirName", "dir", filename="test.py")
```

I'm getting an error

> DIR_PATH = Path(**file**).parent/parentDir/childDir/fileName

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'WindowsPath' and 'tuple'

Comment: There is  bit of confusion as to what asterisk does for parameter(s). Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters If you want  it to be optional make it keyword parameter. Also, at the moment `fileName` is mandatory keyword parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change it to this:

```
def saveFile(parentDir, fileName, childDir=""):
   ...

saveFile("dirName", "test.py")
saveFile("dirName", "test.py", childDir="dir")
```

It will work with the rest of your code. It sets the default to an empty string so it still works with

```
DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).parent/parentDir/childDir/fileName
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```py
def saveFile(parentDir, childDir=None, fileName=None):
```

i.e. make both `childDir` and `fileName` be optional, with defaults of `None` (or whatever makes more sense for default arguments).

Or change the order of the arguments, if you only want `childDir` to be optional:

```py
def saveFile(parentDir, fileName, childDir=None):
```

Or you could do something like this:

```py
def saveFile(parentDir, fileName, **kwargs):
   childDir = kwargs.get("childDir", None)
```

Which would let you have many optional keyword arguments.

I'd go for one of the first two options personally, unless you have good reasons not to.

Comment: Used the first suggestion but when i passed parantDir and filename excluding childName i.e ``saveFile("dirName", fileName="test.py")`` i got an error ``TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'WindowsPath' and 'NoneType'``. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I found a work around, by using if statement.

Comment: Well, yes, if you don't pass a `childDir` then its value will be `None`. If that's no use to you you either need to change the default to be something other than `None` or to check within the function what its value is, and act appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

`childDir` is a `tuple` and already optional because of the `*`.

You have to make it a string.

```
DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / parentDir / '/'.join(childDir) / fileName
```